# how to use replace in javascript for special characters

Tags: javascript

I want to make this:

```
[:fr]french[:de]german[:en]english[:]
```

Look like this:

```
<!--:fr-->french<!--:de-->german<!--:en-->english<!--:-->
```

I have tried:

```
string.replace("[:", "<!--:");
```

and

```
string.replace("]", "-->");
```

but no luck,

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

```
str = str.replace(/\[(:[a-z]*)\]/g, "<!--$1-->");
```